# Function to get the power sets of a set in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to write a function in F# to get the powersets of a set. So far I have written :

```
let rec powerset = function
    |[] -> [[]]
    | [x] -> [[x]; []]
    |x::xs -> [x] :: (List.map (fun n -> [x; n]) xs) @ powerset xs;;
```

but this isn't returning the cases that have 3 or more elements, only the pairs, the single elements, and the empty set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, here is a working solution:

```
let rec powerset = 
   function
   | [] -> [[]]
   | (x::xs) -> 
      let xss = powerset xs 
      List.map (fun xs' -> x::xs') xss @ xss
```

See you only have to use this trick:

> for each element `x` you there half of the elements of the powerset will include `x` and half will not

so you recursively generate the powerset of the remaining elements `xss` and concat the two parts (`List.map (fun xs' -> x::xs') xss` will prepend the `x` to each of those)

But please note that this is not tail recursive and will blow the stack for bigger lists - you can take this idea and try to implement it with `seq` or make a tail-recursive version if you like

---

### Using `seq`

Here is a version that uses seq and the *bijection* between the binary representation of natural numbers (a subset of those) and the subsets of a set (you map the elements to digits and set 1 if the corresponding element is in the subset and 0 if not):

```
let powerset (xs : 'a seq) : 'a seq seq =
    let digits (n : bigint) : bool seq =
        Seq.unfold (fun n -> 
            if n <= 0I 
            then None 
            else Some (n &&& 1I = 1I, n >>> 1))
            n
    let subsetBy (i : bigint) : 'a seq =
        Seq.zip xs (digits i)
        |> Seq.choose (fun (x,b) -> if b then Some x else None)
    seq { 0I .. 2I**(Seq.length xs)-1I }
    |> Seq.map subsetBy
```

this will work for things like `powerset [1..100]` but it might take a long time to enumerate them all ;) (but it should not take to much memory...)

Comment: Tail recursion is probably only a theoretical concern since the size of the powerset grows so quickly - you'll run out of memory way before you overflow the stack.

Comment: @kvb true ... guess it's a reflex of mine

Comment: Using a `seq` might still be beneficial if you would only consume a reasonably-sized prefix of the full result, though.

Comment: @kvb added a possibility with a twist ;)